# How do I make sure the where query executes in the order of the IDs it receives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Profile`, which `has_many :ratings`. I am trying to retrieve the set of profiles that have a specific `rating` attribute (aka `speed` in this instance) and I want to rank the profiles according to their `rating.speed`.

So, I have the following statement:

```
# profile_ids has the correct order I want.
profile_ids = current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).pluck(:profile_id)
# @profiles doesn't...for some strange reason.
@profiles = Profile.where(id: profile_ids)
```

The issue that's happening is that the order of the IDs inside `profile_ids` is not the same order of the `Profiles` being returned to `@profiles`.

Specifically, look at this:

```
> current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).pluck(:profile_id)
   (9.6ms)  SELECT "ratings"."profile_id" FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "ratings"."speed" DESC  [["user_id", 7]]
=> [5, 18, 14, 7, 22, 13, 9, 17]
> @profiles.all.map(&:id)
  Profile Load (7.0ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" IN (5, 18, 14, 7, 22, 13, 9, 17)
=> [18, 9, 13, 17, 22, 14, 5, 7]
```

So notice that the order of `ids` from `@profiles` is different than the `ids` generated from `profile_ids`, which indicates that it was reordered.

Comment: Can you run both the commands multiple times and post the sample output? 6-7 should be enough

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Your comment and updated answer on the other question will work here as well. So if you add it here, I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: What I don't understand is why is this happening to you? Which DB are you using?

Comment: I think it has to do with the `where` clause. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: The database is free to return results in any order it pleases when there is no ORDER BY clause, the order of things in an IN has nothing at all to do with the order that your results will be in. Don't do two queries at all, use a JOIN so that you can apply your `ORDER BY speed desc` to the whole query.

Comment: @muistooshort Care to add an answer so we can see some code? Also remember that the `order` is on the associated record (i.e. the `rating`) and not on the returned record, i.e. the `profile`.

Comment: @muistooshort I have read something like that before, but it never happened to me. marc: I stumbled upon a post, can you tell me how many rows are there in your table?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Not that many, `15` in development, which is where the issue is happening. But I don't want it to happen in production where there will be many more rows.

Comment: @marcamillion seems to be a problem with Postgre then. In any case, since rails is about convention, I encourage you to enforce `order by` clause in your queries as per mu's suggestion so that the problem never occurs across any DB.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I would love to be able to enforce `.order` in my queries, but I can't quite figure out how to do that on associated objects.

Comment: @marcamillion There's a second answer on your previous question. That should help you.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal not exactly. Also it seems to take longer than the `Profile.find` query.